# Extension point for project directories

Tags: svn, monodevelop, add-in

I want to write an add-in that will checkout an SVN repository. Plan is that user right-clicks on a directory, clicks on "SVN Checkout". Add-in asks for its URL and revision number. When OKed, add-in calls "svn co -r xxx URL", shows the result, and refreshes the directory.

I newly have started learning how to write add-in for Monodevelop, and there is not much information about it as far as I see, thus, I need to ask what the extension point of context menu of a project directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented on the [MonoDevelop website](http://www.monodevelop.com/developers/articles/extending-the-project-pad/).

However your best bet is to review the [MonoDevelop source code](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop).

The extension point for a project's context menu is:

```
<Extension path = "/MonoDevelop/Ide/ContextMenu/ProjectPad">
```

Inside that you will need to add your command probably with a condition so it only appears for directories:

```
<Condition id="ItemType" value="IFolderItem">
    <CommandItem id = "YourNamespace.YourCommandId" />
</Condition>
```

Then you can define your command with a handler.

```
<Extension path = "/MonoDevelop/Ide/Commands/Project">
    <Command
        id = "YourNamespace.YourCommandId"
        _description = "desc"
        _label = "your label"
        defaultHandler = "YourNamespace.YourHandler" />
</Extension>
```

YourHandler would then be derived from MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandHandler and override the Run method.